# como sumar dos series pandas

Tags: pandas

```
s1 = pd.Series(['2', '4', '6', '8', '10'])
s2 = pd.Series(['1','3','5','7','9'])

s1+s2

0     21
1     43
2     65
3     87
4    109
```

Como observan lo que obtengo es un "**`concat`**" de los valores, con su respectivo indice y lo que necesito es la suma de ellos
GRACIAS A QUIEN ME PUEDA AYUDAR.

Comment: Me parece que el inconveniente se debe a que estás declarando cada uno de los elementos en las series como caracteres. No uses las comillas simples. Intentalo y cuentanos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto :

```
a=[1,24,5,5]
b=[9,91,81,5]
Total =[ int(b[x]) + int(a[x]) for x in range(0,len(a)-1)]
```

O puedes usar

```
Total =[ sum(int(x)) for x in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: Sii!!! efectivamente, tu sugerencia me funciono para otras cosas que necesitaba realizar! Gracias, tengo que realizar otras operaciones con esa lista... Soy nueva con este lenguaje, muchas gracias!!